# VB2010 List(Of String) to multiple labels

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms, list, label

I have 64 panels, each containing two strings of data. For testing purposes I used a random number generator to provide my data.

I created a list of strings (64 strings total, containing "," separating the two pieces of data per panel) and now need to write them to each label.

I need to find a way to split the string data (which I know how) and write to each label.

For example: the first string will be split and added to the first panel called Label1a and Label1b, 2nd string split to Label2a and Label2b, etc..

```
Dim LotData As New List(Of String)

Dim randomnumber1 As Integer, randomnumber2 As Integer, randomchance As Integer
Dim slotnumber As String
Dim sbailes As String
Dim stemp As String

Randomize()

Dim n As Integer
For n = 1 To 64

  randomnumber1 = CInt(Rnd() * 1000000000)
  randomnumber2 = CInt(Rnd() * 300)
  randomchance = CInt(Rnd() * 1000)

  slotnumber = Convert.ToString(randomnumber1)

  'approximately 50% of the lots will be empty in this test
  If randomchance >= 500 Then
    sbailes = CStr(randomnumber2)
  Else
    sbailes = "0"
  End If

  LotData.Add(slotnumber & "," & sbailes)
Next
```

My only solution is to write 128 lines of code, manually adding each string in but I know there must be a better solution than that...

Comment: Is this Windows Forms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to get a control by string name. I have some methods that help to do this here (put them in a module)

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(ByVal parent As Control) As ArrayList
    Return ChildControls(Of Control)(parent)
End Function

<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(Of T)(ByVal parent As Control) As ArrayList
    Dim result As New ArrayList()
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(ctrl)
        result.AddRange(ChildControls(Of T)(ctrl))
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Public Function GetControlByName(ByRef parent As Control, ByVal name As String) As Control
    For Each c As Control In parent.ChildControls
        If c.Name = name Then
            Return c
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Then in your method, you can get the control by name, depending on an integer counting from 1 to 64 like so:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 64
    CType(GetControlByName(Me, "Label" & i.ToString() & "A"), Label).Text = _
        LotData(i).Split(",").FirstOrDefault()
    CType(GetControlByName(Me, "Label" & i.ToString() & "B"), Label).Text = _
        LotData(i).Split(",").LastOrDefault()
Next
```

Oh! You can also save yourself the trouble of adding all the controls to the form at design time by doing something like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 64
    Dim lblA As New Label()
    Dim lblB As New Label()
    lblA.Name = "Label" & i.ToString() & "A"
    lblB.Name = "Label" & i.ToString() & "B"
    ' do something about Locations here
    Me.Controls.Add(lblA)
    Me.Controls.Add(lblB)
    ' you could even add them to your panel.controls
Next
```

(don't forget exception handling)